# How to Wait the command to finish - gcloud config configurations activate

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a bash script which activate multiples configurations with following gcloud command:

`gcloud config configurations activate MYENV`

In the most case, this command works instantly, sometimes it takes 10 secondes or more than 60 secondes.

I am using sleep(10) ... but it is not the best way. Anyone, have an idea on how to wait that gcloud command finish?

Even if I can use return=$? , I will not know if this command waits for the command to be finished.

Comment: This might help: [How can I wait for a Google App Engine operation to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62885951/3776858)

Comment: Thanks but it works only for app engine ressources?

Comment: What do you mean by **command works instantly**? What happens when it does not? That command changes the configuration. It does not create credentials. Are you later having a credential issue? Edit your question so that we know what the actual issue is.

Comment: Im just wondering what is need of activating different config on same machine instance

Comment: I activate multiple configurations because I need to send files to all my Environment (DEV, PROD, INT).

Comment: I tried everything, and I have always the same problem. When I activate my DEV env, It switch to int or prod configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wait` command to use for the last command identified by its PID:

```shell
#!/bin/usr/env bash

# launch your command in the background
gcloud config configurations activate MYENV &

# wait for the command to finish
wait $!

echo 'Configuration $MYENV activited'
```

Comment: thanks but the same problem with this solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm breaking a personal practice by answering a question by proposing an alternative approach but...

`gcloud config configurations` adjusts `gcloud`'s global state by swapping in a set of configuration variables. These variables are all readily represented directly in `gcloud` commands.

Particularly when (writing) scripts, I feel a better practice is to use flags and variables on commands explicitly.

Rather than:

```sh
for CONFIG in "foo" "bar" "baz"
do
  gcloud config configurations activate ${CONFIG}
  gcloud compute instances delete instance-01 \
  --quiet
done
```

Where parameters (flags) of `gcloud compute instances delete insurance-01` are implicit.

Versus:

```sh
for PROJECT in "foo" "bar" "baz"
do
  for ZONE in "us-west1-c" "us-central1-a"
  do
    gcloud compute instances delete instance-01 \
    --zone=${ZONE} \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --quiet
  done
done
```

Where you:

- avoid any global update "pauses"
- avoid breaking a `gcloud` session running in a different process
- have a more explicit and understandable set of commands
- can pump the script output to a log file to see exactly what ran

Personally, I discourage use of `gcloud` config for anything other than the unavoidable i.e. `gcloud config ... account` and that may be all.